# Use DragNDrop Listview in ScrollView

Tags: android, scrollview

I want to use `DragNDrop` `ListView` in `ScrollView`, I used `DragNDrop` `ListView` at [Link Here](https://sites.google.com/site/ericbharlow/sample-code/DragNDrop.zip?attredirects=0&d=1). But I can scroll and Touch for `ScrollView`, I can't drag and drop item in `ListView`.

Please help me to drag and drop `ListView`. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using this library, its perfect for what you need:

https://github.com/bauerca/drag-sort-listview